# Flapdoodle Embedded Mongo process won't start

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, junit

I'm trying to have an Embedded Mongo instance run while performing my unit tests. I am using the flapdoodle embedded mongo package to achieve this, but getting an error while attempting to start the tests.

My build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:3.3.0'
}
```

And the test file:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    UserServiceImpl userService;

    @MockBean
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @MockBean
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        assertThat(userService).isNotNull();
        assertThat(userRepository).isNotNull();
    }

    public User getUser(String authId) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setAuth0Id(authId);
        user.setUserImage("img");
        user.setEmail("email@mail.com");
        user.setName("User 1");
        user.setId("1");
        return user;
    }

    @Test
    public void findByAuth0IdReturnsCorrectly() {
        String id = "helloIamTheId";
        User user = getUser(id);
        when(userRepository.findByAuth0Id(id)).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));
        assertThat(userService.findByAuth0Id(id)).isEqualTo(Optional.of(user));
    }
}
```

The error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start process: <EOF>
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.AbstractMongoProcess.onAfterProcessStart(AbstractMongoProcess.java:79) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.AbstractProcess.<init>(AbstractProcess.java:113) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.process-3.1.6.jar:na]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.AbstractMongoProcess.<init>(AbstractMongoProcess.java:53) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodProcess.<init>(MongodProcess.java:50) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable.start(MongodExecutable.java:44) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable.start(MongodExecutable.java:34) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Executable.start(Executable.java:109) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.process-3.1.6.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1930) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1872) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 100 common frames omitted
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and It seems related to version 3.3.0.

Using 3.2.8 worked for me:

de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:3.2.8

Comment: No luck with using version 3.2.8 for myself. It looks like it works if I set the Mongo server version to 3.6.2, so must be down to the actual mongo server, not ideal (the real version the app will use is 4.4.1) but will do for now. Thanks!

Comment: 3.6.2 also helped me